# Intrasubject coefficient of variation for cross-over sample size calculation

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size, statistical-power, effect-size, crossover-study

I would like to calculate the required sample size for a crossover design based on a study conducted in a parallel-design. I understand that one needs the within subject CV. Unfortunately, the authors only report M(SD) for each group and each time point (treatment Baseline, Control baseline, ...).

Is there any way to roughly estimate the intrasubject CV or is there any measure that I can substitute the CV with?

Also, I am thinking about contacting the authors to ask for the CV - am I right in my understanding that I just need the CV from the treatment group?